# How to connect to Database from NUnit Test project?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, testing, mocking, nunit

I am new to NUnit testing for asp.net mvc web app, project I want to test using entity frame work to connect with the database, from the test project I need to connect to the same data base of the project which I want to test .

controller which I am testing looks like as below.

```
public class EXController : Controller
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;
    private readonly CommonDbContext _commonContext;

    public EXController(CommonDbContext commonContext, AppDbContext context)
    {
        _commonContext = commonContext;
        _context = context;
    }

     public ActionResult Index()
    {
    // some simple code.
    }
}
```

I am trying to write NUnit tests as below:
In references section of the test project I added Project under testing as dll, I am able to 
access all the classes from the project I want to test.

CommonDbContext and AppDbContext are the classes which I am using in the code under testing to connect with the data base, these classes takes argument as the connectionstring.

so I am passing the connection string to these classes to connect with the data base from Nunit test project.

I am trying to connect to the data base in NUnit test project, using following connection string.

```
CommonDbContext objcdb = new CommonDbContext("metadata =\"res://*/Data.CommonDbModel.CommonDbModel.csdl|res://*/Data.CommonDbModel.CommonDbModel.ssdl|res://*/Data.CommonDbModel.CommonDbModel.msl\";provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=\"server=servername;database=databasename;integratedsecurity=False;user id=userid;password=password");

AppDbContext Objadb = new AppDbContext("metadata = \"res://*/Data.AppDbModel.AppDbModel.csdl|res://*/Data.AppDbModel.AppDbModel.ssdl|res://*/Data.AppDbModel.AppDbModel.msl\";provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=\"server=servername;database=databasename;integratedsecurity=False;user id=userid;password=password");

// creating instance for the contrller I want to test
ExController obController = new CLINController(objcdb, Objadb);
```

I am getting below exception when I am trying to connect with the database from NUnit test project.

```
Exception:
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 164.

**Stack Trace:**
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(IDictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, IList`1 validKeywords)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, IList`1 validKeywords)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at BidMaster.Web.Infrastructure.CurrentUser.get_User() in D:\BWM_sprint3_newcopy\BidMaster.Web\BidMaster.Web\Infrastructure\CurrentUser.cs:line 30
   at BidMaster.Web.Controllers.CLINController.Index(Nullable`1 id) in D:\BWM_sprint3_newcopy\BidMaster.Web\BidMaster.Web\Controllers\CLINController.cs:line 51
   at BidMaster.Test.Controllers.CLINControllerTests.IndexTest() in D:\BWM_sprint3_newcopy\BidMaster.Test\BidMaster.Test\Controllers\CLINControllerTests.cs:line 47
```

Any thing wrong with the connectin string which I am using? Please help me, please explain how to connect with the database from Unit test project. I am new to testing.

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests should never go past a certain scope (the unit, generally a class). In other words, you shouldn't touch the DB - that's already system (integration testing).

Your unit test should rather just test the logic inside that `Index` method (for example), whilst mocking the layer handling the DB calls.

Something along these lines (using [RhinoMocks](https://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-mocks) or other mocking tool):

```cs
_commonDbContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<CommonDbContext>();
_appDbContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<AppDbContext>();

ExController obController = new CLINController(_commonDbContext, _appDbContext );
```

Otherwise, if you want to go down the system test path, you would have to issue a request towards the url (port number & all) your service resides, not through a direct reference to it.

Only wrote this as an answer because it's too long for a comment, you'll need to provide more details regarding the method you're trying to test if you need specific answers.

Comment: I need to connect with the same data base which I am using for the Project under Testing, from the unit test project, because my requirement is to test the data which is return by the stored procedures as well as part of testing, if I MOCK the DB I could not test the data which is return by store procedures, please help me how to connect with the same data base which I am using for the Project under Testing, from the unit test project with out mocking the DB.